# Create a cron job to append a line to a file every day

Tags: ubuntu, cron

There is a file located at specific location and it gets back normal everyday so I have to edit it again I want to create a **cron job** so that file gets edited everyday.

I just need to add a line to that file in the end.

The file is located at

```
/usr/local/data/conf/info.conf
```

and I want to add this line at the end of the file everyday

```
USERNAME_DATA=’SUPERADMIN’
```

How can I set up a cron job to append this line to the file?

Answer (score 2):

**To add something to the end of the file**:

```
echo "USERNAME_DATA=’SUPERADMIN’" >> /usr/local/data/conf/info.conf
```

**To configure a cron** to do this automatically every day - you just need to edit a crontab file, to do this execute:

```
crontab -e
```

and then add a line inside of the opened file:

```
23 17 * * * echo "USERNAME_DATA=’SUPERADMIN’" >> /usr/local/data/conf/info.conf
```

In this example it will be executed at 17:23 every day, it's easy set a different schedule https://corenominal.org/2016/05/12/howto-setup-a-crontab-file/

Answer (score 0):

This [page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cron#Crontab_format) can help you out. It tells you how format your crontab file properly.

This page tells:

> minute hour day_of_month month day_of_week command

Here a little guide:

- type **crontab -e** in a console (a document is just opening)
- type for example **@daily /home/user/here/this_script_adds_soemthing.sh** (it is a special tag, so do not be confused)

And in the script you write something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

text=$(cat /usr/local/data/conf/info.conf)

echo "$text""USERNAME_DATA=’SUPERADMIN’" >> /usr/local/data/conf/info.conf
```

And do not forget to `chmod +x /home/user/here/this_script_adds_soemthing.sh` your script.

Comment: i gave permission 775 to the file but still getting this error  
 /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: I don't want bother you, but typing _/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter_  in Google gives you many results. While reading some of the them, it can be that the file has invalid line endings (\r\n (windows), \n (linux) and so on) or you just don't have bash. Type `echo $SHELL` for considering or by just typing and entering `bash` in your console. You could look with `which bash` where it is loacted and replace the _#!/bin/bash_ header